# How to create a recursive function in SASS that can accept a key and return a list of all ancestors?

Tags: css, function, recursion, sass, sass-maps

I am trying to create a `get-ancestors()` function that takes a `$key` and returns all ancestors in a list like this:

```
$ancestors-map : (
    'button' : (),
     'small-button' : (
            'button'
    ),
    'hollow-button' : (
            'button',
    ),
    'small-hollow-button' : (
            'small-button',
            'hollow-button',
    )
);
```

Calling `get-ancestors('small-hollow-button')` should return `('small-button', 'button', 'hollow-button', 'button')`

I would like to then remove duplicated ancestors, but I should be able to figure that out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have tried many things, and the closest I got was with something like this:

```
@function get-ancestors($ancestors, $key) {
    $value: map-get($ancestors-map, $key);

    @if length($value) == 0 {
        @return $ancestors;
    }

    @each $ancestor in $value {
        @return get-parents($ancestors, $ancestor);
    }    
}
```

Edit: Thanks for the answer, here's my final setup with an expanded example:

```
$ancestors: (
    'red' : (),
    'background-color' : ('red'),
    'button' : (),
    'red-bg' : ('background-color'),
    'small-button' : ('button'),
    'hollow-red-button' : ('button', 'red-bg'),
    'small-hollow-red-button' : ('small-button', 'hollow-red-button')
);

@function get-ancestors($key, $list: ()) {
  $key-list: map-get($ancestors, $key);

  @if length($key-list) == 0 { 
    $list: join($list, $key)
  } @else {
    @each $parent in $key-list {
      $list: get-ancestors($parent, $list);
    }
    $list: join($list, $key)
  }

  @return $list;
}

.cool {
  content: get-ancestors($key: 'small-hollow-red-button');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not recursive, but I think this is what you're looking for.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8437673865a1a4c6bfe9ea2190607a6e)

```
$ancestors-map: (
    'button' : (),
    'small-button' : ('button'),
    'hollow-button' : ('button'),
    'small-hollow-button' : ('small-button', 'hollow-button')
);

@function get-ancestors($ancestors, $key) {
  $key-list: map-get($ancestors, $key);
  @if length($key-list) == 0 { @return $ancestors; }

  $list: ();
  @each $parent in $key-list {
    $list: append($list, $parent, comma);
    $list: append($list, map-get($ancestors, $parent));
  }

  @return $list;
}
```

Comment: This was close, and ultimately lead to my complete solution. Thanks a bunch!